# Call a jquery function dynamically from a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

Say, I have JSON data getting from API. I want to use a value of JSON key to call a user-defined jquery function.

The data I am getting from the server is :

```
{
    "question":"What is your age?",
    "graphType":"horizontalBar",
}
```

Now I am having a function in my script which is named as horizontalBar.

```
( function( $ ){
$.fn.horizontalBar = function(data){
   //do some stuff
}
})( jQuery );
```

So, now I want something like this in order to call the function:

```
$().json.graphType(data);
```

Here is what I searched and tried to call it:

```
window[json.graphType](data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$(<selector of target object>)[json.graphType](data);
```

This will apply the jquery-method named in `json.graphType` on the selected jQuery target object.

From your post I now guess, that you don't even have a selector. So, `<selector of target object>` is void:

```
$()[json.graphType](data);
```

Comment: Well, if this is the right solution for you, then maybe you should click it as "accepted answer"? ;-)